# Besides NY, which other US states, if any, mandate the appointment of public historians?

Tags: united-states, law, government, new-york

As per the website of [The Association of Public Historians of New York State](https://aphnys.org) :

> The Association of Public Historians of New York State is a 501(c)3 non-profit professional organization that represents the 1,600+ government-appointed historians in the state. Under state law, every county and municipality in New York is required to have an appointed historian to document, preserve, interpret, and share the history of their communities. It is part of the state’s commitment to ensuring that New Yorkers have access to quality educational experiences enriched by cultural heritage resources.

Comment: The US itself has a government-appointed historian. His title is 
"Historian of the United States House of Representatives" and it's currently: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matthew_Wasniewski

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historian_of_the_United_States_House_of_Representatives#:~:text=The%20Historian%20of%20the%20United,institutional%20memory%20for%20the%20institution.

Comment: Thanks. What about at the state level? Is there another state with as broad a program of public history?

Comment: I live in one of the United States; my state has a State Historical Commission.  I imagine other states do too.  Why don't you research "state historical commissions", with a little help from Google.

Comment: Looking for a high-level overview. And to avoid 50 searches.

Comment: @zadrozny - but your question asks which other states, so you are asking folks here to do you search for you and then summarize. My contribution: New Mexico has an 'Office of the State Historian', part of the State Records Center and Archives.

Comment: No such expectation. Hoping for a single resource describing public history programs by state. Thanks.